# AJAX Calls within jQuery Loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code, which is working (?), but I guess I can do it simpler and more elegantly. I need to invoke a method when everything is completed (channelsVideos array is filled). The console.log function at the end runs and display the array. The objects are in it, but it is displayed as Array[0] in the console. Is this normal? All I want is to be sure that all the data is donwloaded before creating the UI elements.

```
menuItemsAndTabs: [],
categoriesAndChannels: [],
channelsVideos: [],

...
...
...

getChannelsAndVideos: function() {
    $.each(MyApp.menuItemsAndTabs[1].menuItem.tabs, function(index, value) {            
        var _id = value._id;
        var ajaxGetChannels = $.getJSON(MyApp.CONSTANTS.URLS.API + "/api/assets/" + _id, function(response) {

        }).done(function(response) {
            $.each(response.channels, function(ind, val) {
                MyApp.categoriesAndChannels.push({  
                    channel: {
                        categoryName: value.label,
                        channelName: val.channelId,
                        channelId: val._id              
                    }

                });
                var ajaxGetVideos = $.getJSON(MyApp.CONSTANTS.URLS.API + "/videos/channel/" + val.channelId, function(response) {

                }).done(function(response) {
                    $.each(response.videos, function(ind, val) {
                        MyApp.channelsVideos.push({
                            channelName: val.channelId,
                            videos: {
                                title: val.title
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            });


            });
        });


    console.log(MyApp.channelsVideos);


},
```

Comment: I would suggest combining the multiple HTTP requests into 1.

Comment: I would suggest migrating this question to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Stack Overflow is about problems with code. Not about improving code that's working perfectly fine. That's what Code Review is for.

Comment: So, currently you don't know how/when to *`invoke a method when everything is completed`* ? Is that correct? If so, it's not really a code review question as there is a request for "missing functionality"

Comment: something like https://jsfiddle.net/jaromanda/5cmhg6ap/ perhaps?

Comment: perhaps even https://jsfiddle.net/jaromanda/5cmhg6ap/1/ - can't test for you :p

Comment: The console.log function at the end runs and display the array. The objects are in it, but it is displayed as Array[0] in the console. Is this normal? All I want is to be sure that all the data is donwloaded before creatign the UI elements.

Comment: Hi Jaromanda X, What are the three dots in line: MyApp.channelsVideos.push(...[].concat(...results.map(({channelsVideos}) => channelsVideos))); Do they have a special meaning or do they just stand  for the array names?